# Haskell parse error when loading file with list definintion

Tags: list, haskell

I am guessing this is a total beginners error. I have a hs-file in it I have written

```
let mylist = [1,2,3]
```

When I run it using :load in ghci I get the following error

*parse error (possibly incorrect indentation)*

The statement works when I am in Prelude mode. So basically I am wondering why is this not working when loading a file, and what's the difference between Prelude and Main?

Comment: Can you post the program source code and place it in {} tags?

Comment: That was all I had written. Misstook Haskell for Python :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In GHCi the syntax is a little different because it acts sort of like you're in a `do`-block, so you have to use the `let x = ...` form. In a Haskell source file you can just drop the `let` and write:

```
mylist = [1,2,3]
```

---

As for the difference between `Prelude` and `Main`, the `Prelude` is a standard module which [defines the most common Haskell types and functions](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html), and it's imported by default into every Haskell module.

`Main` is just the default name for a module that does not have `module Foo where ...` at the top.

When using GHCi with default settings, the prompt shows which modules are currently in scope. If you just started GHCi without loading a file, this will be just the `Prelude`, so the prompt looks like this:

```
Prelude>
```

After loading a module, the prompt changes to show the new module that was brought into scope. As mentioned previously, this will be `Main` if you didn't give it a different name.

```
*Main>
```

The asterisk means that the module has been loaded in interpreted mode, which means that everything that is in scope in the module will also be in scope at the GHCi prompt, including stuff imported from other modules such as the `Prelude`.

You can bring additional modules into scope by using the `:m` command. Notice how the prompt changes to show the additional module.

```
*Main> :m + Data.List
*Main Data.List>
```

For more information, type `:help` in GHCi or [read the GHCi chapter of the GHC User's Guide](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/ghci.html).

Comment: NB: it is good Haskell style to give an explicit type signature to top level declarations.

Comment: Thanks! I have been doing a lot of Python and seeing the interpreter I wrongly assumed that there was more to it than just running a file of choice.